# Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 remapped delete key

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, workspaces

On Ubuntu 16.04, delete worked normally. Right after upgrading to 18.04.1, my delete key now switches my workspace to "Workspace 1," but does not delete. If I plug in the same keyboard to Ubuntu 16.04, delete functions normally. If I plug in a different keyboard to Ubuntu 18.04, the same bizarre behavior happens. Here's the output from xev when I press delete:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967270 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Please add to your question the setting of your locale, keyboard and language. Also if you have customized any keyboard mapping in 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Bizzarely, Delete was set to "Move window to workspace 1" in Gnome keyboard settings. Previously, this was set to "ca-!" No idea why upgrading would set this to delete, but hope this helps someone!